# Warming Lambda Function with Cloudwatch schedule rules

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-vpc

I'm trying to warm a lambda (inside VPC which access a private RDS) function with cloudwatch. The rate is 5 minutes (only for experimental) I intend to make it 35 minutes later on.

After I saw the cloudwatch logs which indicate that the function has been called (and completed which I have set up a condition if no input was given, return an API gateway response immediately), I call the function from API gateway URL.

However, I'm still getting that cold starts which it return a response in 2sec. If I do it again, I get the response in 200ms.

So my question is:

1. What did I do wrong? can I actually warm a lambda function with a cloudwatch schedule?
2. Is dropping the request immediately affects this behaviour? the db connection is not established if the request is from cloudwatch

Thanks!

### ****EDIT****

I tried to connect to the db before I drop the function when it's called by cloudwatch. But it doesn't change anything. The first request through API call still around 2s and the next ones are around 200ms.

### ****EDIT 2****

I tried to remove the schedule entirely and the cold start achieves 9s. So I guess the 2s has discounted the cold start. Is it possible that the problem lies in other services? Such as API Gateway?

Comment: So is CloudWatch actually invoking the Lambda? or is something else calling out to API Gateway to invoke the Lambda?

Comment: What language is your Lambda function written in?  *"the db connection is not established if the request is from cloudwatch"* I assume means your code deliberately does not connect to the db in this condition.  Is that correct?  If so, how do you know this is actually a cold start, rather than something like a relatively long amount of time required to initialize the db connection?

Comment: @KMo the cloudwatch is invoking lambda directly

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot it's in Golang. Yes, I'm not connecting to db if it's an invokation from cloudwatch. hmm good point. I'll try connecting db connection in each cloudwatch invokations and see if anything changes.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I tried connecting to the db & ping it before I dropped the request but it seems it doesn't change anything. the first request is still around 2s and the next ones are around 200ms. Hmm could it be the API Gateway? because I only pinged the lambda

Comment: It could be.  Be sure both services are invoking the Lambda function exactly the same way -- specifically, be sure it's the same version or alias.  Different versions of the "same" Lambda function don't share containers.

Comment: I think it's the API gateway but I'm not sure. After I removed the cloudwatch schedule, it turns out that the cold start will be around 9s. So I guess the 2s has discounted the cold start